# file_get_content failed to open stream when im trying to receive my guests location using third party API

Tags: php

I try to catch my website visitors IPs and location (country, city and region) for counting them. When I'm trying to use `file_get_content` to get stuff from third party API I get :

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\OpenServer\domains\testip\copyfunction.php on line 20

I am kinda new to using third party APIs so thats why I have no idea. How can I authorize in HTTP protocol? Can you help me out?

```
// Get IP address
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') ?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') ?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') ?: getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// Get JSON object
$jsondata = file_get_contents("http://timezoneapi.io/api/ip/?" . $ip);

// Decode
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

// Request OK?
if($data['meta']['code'] == '200'){

    // Example: Get the city parameter
    echo "City: " . $data['data']['city'] . "<br>";

    // Example: Get the users time
    echo "Time: " . $data['data']['datetime']['date_time_txt'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Mike.While I suspect your problem is the call to the time zone API, it is hard to make out, as you are not clear as to what file `copyfunction.php` is, and where line 20 is. May I also suggest that you don't do the analysis of the IP address during processing, but wait and do it as a batch job later on if this is just for statistics.

Comment: hello! Thank you for response.

Comment: hello! Thank you for response. Its just for my little script I am  testing it out on my local machine. I just need to see ip adresses and locations of any visitor to my future website.  it seems I cant authorize to this third party API, so I want to ask anyone who did the same thing how they opened the stream on HTTP request. What do you mean by saying if i registred at the app? you mean registering on the website   http://timezoneapi.io/api/ip/??